# how can I filter tests on multiple criteria

Tags: junit, testng, jbehave

I have a large set of tests that I would like to be able to filter so that I can run specific tests.  I am currently using JBehave with JUnit

If I have three sets of criteria
priority with values from 1 to 5
colours with possible values of red, green, blue and yellow
day with possible values of the days of the week

If I set up a 'filter' of priority == 1, colour == blue, day == Tuesday then I will get all of the tests where the criteria has either a priority == 1 OR colour == blue OR day == Tuesday.  This is whether I use JUnit, TestNG or the JBehave Meta filters.

What I actually want are only the tests where priority == 1 AND colour == blue AND day == Tuesday.

Is there any framework that I can use to be able to do this?  In the application I will have about 8 different sets of criteria to and each criteria will have a maximum of about 4 values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use TestNG with groups and BeanShell to implement the logic. [Details here](http://beust.com/weblog/2005/09/30/a-date-in-heaven-testng-and-beanshell/).

Comment: Thank you.  I will create a wrapper so that the tests can have an simple way of entering the criteria so that they don't have to write any code.